# Can I just copy "Z location" to all the selected objects?

Tags: transforms, properties

"Copy to selected" copies the complete location X, Y and Z to all the selected objects. I wish to copy only Z location. Please see the images bellow to get idea of what I intend to achieve.

**Before**
[image: before transforms]

**After**
[image: after transforms]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also try another way:

- Switch pivot point type to **Active Element**, toggle **Manipulate Center Points**;
- Select objects, keep one active, then <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

[image]

### UPDATE:

Thanks to Bastien Montagne (aka mont29)'s [commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB177d051126b3ea4a1dec6a016ae67d7f51f233d0), you can find this feature in latest version, now only for Location, but also Rotation, Scale, Dimensions, etc:

[image]

Comment: "toggle Manipulate Center Points" is the key step, and i was not ware of this feature. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The position of the object is defined by it's origin point, but **you can't always assume that the origin is centered when selecting multiple and more complex objects than a cube**.

[image]

That the origins are prefectly centered is a special case, because of the different dimensions or diffenrent kinds of geometry. In this case the **result of the test scene above**  would look like:

[image]

One way to get around this is to **calculate the object position differences of the meshes** and move the objects by adding or subtracting this differences in the axis from the current locations of the objects.

For this case I wrote a small addon to **align multiple objects to the geometry of the active** one. The script calculates the dimensions of every object that is selected and move the objects to the right spot, **independent of the origin's position.**

[image]
*Align objects to the second suzanne*

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Align Geometry",
    "description": "",
    "author": "poor",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 73, 0),
    "location": "Tool Shelf > Tools",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.props import (EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    logic
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# get x,y,z min or max of geometry
def get_geo_min_max(obj, axis):
    axis_coords = []
    # iterate through all vertices
    for face in obj.data.polygons:
        verts_in_face = face.vertices[:]
        for vert in verts_in_face:
            local_point = obj.data.vertices[vert].co
            world_point = obj.matrix_world * local_point
            axis_coords.append(world_point[axis])
    # return the geometry minimum and maximum        
    return min(axis_coords), max(axis_coords)


# align objects to min or max of the reference object
def align_objects_to_min_or_max_of_reference_object(ob_reference, mesh_ob_transform_list, align_axis, extreme_point):
    for i in mesh_ob_transform_list:
        # get the difference of obj maximums
        if extreme_point == "MAX":
            diff = abs(get_geo_min_max(ob_reference, align_axis)[1] - get_geo_min_max(i, align_axis)[1])
        # get the difference of obj minimums
        if extreme_point == "MIN":
            diff = abs(get_geo_min_max(ob_reference, align_axis)[0] - get_geo_min_max(i, align_axis)[0])
        # if current position is higher the reference
        if get_geo_min_max(ob_reference, align_axis)[0] > get_geo_min_max(i, align_axis)[0]:
            i.location[align_axis] += diff
        # if current position is same the reference
        if get_geo_min_max(ob_reference, align_axis)[0] == get_geo_min_max(i, align_axis)[0]:
            i.location[align_axis] -= diff
        # if current position is below the reference
        if get_geo_min_max(ob_reference, align_axis)[0] < get_geo_min_max(i, align_axis)[0]:
            i.location[align_axis] -= diff

# align objects to the center of the reference object
def align_objects_to_center_of_reference_object(ob_reference, mesh_ob_transform_list, align_axis):
    # get extreme points of reference
    ob_ref_extremes = get_geo_min_max(ob_reference, align_axis)
    # calculate axis center
    ob_ref_axis_center = ob_ref_extremes[0] + (0.5 * (ob_ref_extremes[1] - ob_ref_extremes[0]))
    for i in mesh_ob_transform_list:
        # get extreme points of i
        i_extremes = get_geo_min_max(i, align_axis)
        # calculate center
        i_axis_center = i_extremes[0] + (0.5 * (i_extremes[1] - i_extremes[0]))
        # calculate difference
        diff = abs(ob_ref_axis_center - i_axis_center)
        # if current position is above the reference
        if ob_ref_axis_center > i_axis_center:
            i.location[align_axis] += diff
        # if current position is same as reference
        if ob_ref_axis_center == i_axis_center:
            i.location[align_axis] += diff
        # if current position is below as reference
        if ob_ref_axis_center < i_axis_center:
            i.location[align_axis] -= diff

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    ui
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def axisStringToInt(axis_str):
    axes = {
        'X': 0,
        'Y': 1,
        'Z': 2
    }
    return axes[axis_str]

class GeometryAlignSettings(PropertyGroup):
    axes = [
        ('X', "X Axis", ""),
        ('Y', "Y Axis", ""),
        ('Z', "Z Axis", ""),
    ]
    transform = EnumProperty(
        name="Transformation Axes:",
        description="Apply transformation to",
        items=axes
        )

class OBJECT_PT_geometry_align_panel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_geometry_align_panel"
    bl_label = "Align Geometry"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        active_obj = context.active_object
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(scene.geometry_align, "transform", text="")
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.operator("geometryalign.to_max_geo", icon="ZOOMIN")
        row.operator("geometryalign.to_min_geo", icon="ZOOMOUT")
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.operator("geometryalign.to_center_geo", icon="CURSOR")

        if active_obj != None:
            if active_obj.type == "MESH" and active_obj != None:
                layout.label( "Snap to " + active_obj.name )
            else:
                layout.label( "No active mesh" )


class OBJECT_OT_AlignMaxButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "geometryalign.to_max_geo"
    bl_label = "Maximum"
    bl_description = "Align objects to maximum of active object"
    #bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene # get the scene
        objs = bpy.context.selected_objects  # get selected objects
        mesh_objs = [m for m in objs if m.type == "MESH"] # get all mesh objects in selection
        active_obj = scn.objects.active # get active object

        if active_obj != None: # error handling
            if active_obj.type == "MESH":
                axis = axisStringToInt(scn.geometry_align.transform)  # set transform axis: x=0, y=1, z=2
                align_objects_to_min_or_max_of_reference_object (active_obj, mesh_objs, axis, 'MAX')
            else:
                self.report({'INFO'}, "%s is not a mesh object" % (active_obj.name))
        return{'FINISHED'}


class OBJECT_OT_AlignMinButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "geometryalign.to_min_geo"
    bl_label = "Minimum"
    bl_description = "Align objects to minimum of active object"
    #bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene # get the scene
        objs = bpy.context.selected_objects  # get selected objects
        mesh_objs = [m for m in objs if m.type == "MESH"] # get all mesh objects in selection
        active_obj = scn.objects.active # get active object

        if active_obj != None: # error handling
            if active_obj.type == "MESH":
                axis = axisStringToInt(scn.geometry_align.transform)  # set transform axis: x=0, y=1, z=2
                align_objects_to_min_or_max_of_reference_object (active_obj, mesh_objs, axis, 'MIN')
            else:
                self.report({'INFO'}, "%s is not a mesh object" % (active_obj.name))
        return{'FINISHED'}

class OBJECT_OT_AlignCenterButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "geometryalign.to_center_geo"
    bl_label = "Center"
    bl_description = "Align objects to center of active object"
    #bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene # get the scene
        objs = bpy.context.selected_objects  # get selected objects
        mesh_objs = [m for m in objs if m.type == "MESH"] # get all mesh objects in selection
        active_obj = scn.objects.active # get active object

        if active_obj != None: # error handling
            if active_obj.type == "MESH":
                axis = axisStringToInt(scn.geometry_align.transform)  # set transform axis: x=0, y=1, z=2
                align_objects_to_center_of_reference_object (active_obj, mesh_objs, axis)
            else:
                self.report({'INFO'}, "%s is not a mesh object" % (active_obj.name))
        return{'FINISHED'}


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    register and unregister functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.geometry_align = PointerProperty(type=GeometryAlignSettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.geometry_align

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You can center the origin of all the selected objects with `Ctrl Shift Alt C` > *Origin to geometry* (or whatever centering method you like).

Comment: Oops, I meant that I don't think it's necessary to use python, but perhaps I missed something. You can center the origins of multiple objects at once without python..

Comment: @gandalf3 If the origins of all objects are not in the center, it becomes difficult, right? Maybe there is a clever way without it, but I haven't a better idea.

Comment: @poor thanks, this script is bang on and will help me learn script based manupelation

Comment: @poor Wow more than expected. This creates new possibilities.